# ckan harvester: "No module named pika" error

Tags: plugins, ckan, data-harvest

On a ckan instance running ok, I installed the harvester extension following this guide: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest

these are the steps I followed:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan

sudo pip install -e git+https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-harvest.git@stable#egg=ckanext-harvest

cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/src/ckanext-harvest
sudo pip install -r pip-requirements.txt
```

This is the content of pip-requirements.txt:

```
pika==0.9.8
redis==2.10.1
```

I continue configuring the plugin, everything seems to work ok. I have it running at http://localhost/harvest. Then I create a new source, and when I want to start the gather command I get this error:

```
$ . /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
$ cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/src/ckanext-harvest
$ paster --plugin=ckanext-harvest harvester gather_consumer --config=/etc/ckan/default/production.ini 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/commands/harvester.py", line 125, in command
    from ckanext.harvest.queue import get_gather_consumer, gather_callback
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/queue.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pika
ImportError: No module named pika
```

I'm pretty sure there must be something really silly with the virtualenv (python newbie here)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used `sudo pip`. Because of how python's virtualenv works, if you want to use `sudo` to install into the virtualenv, you need to give full path to `pip`. Something like this would work

```
sudo /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/pip -e git+https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-harvest.git@stable#egg=ckanext-harvest
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest
sudo /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/pip install -r pip-requirements.txt
```